# Remove between UITableView and UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have an `UITableView` which I am trying to make the background color of the first cell match the color of the `UINavigationBar`, as seen in the screenshot below.

[image: iOS Simulator Screenshot]

However, as you can see, there is a dark border between both objects which I don't know where is coming from.

Moreover, it is evident that the tone of the color used is not the same in both cases, despite using the same `[UIColor colorWithRed:]` code. This is not the main problem, but I wanted to mention this too.

Any thoughts?

**EDIT**

viewDidLoad:

```
self.tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.97 green:0.97 blue:0.97 alpha:1.0];
self.tableView.scrollEnabled = NO;

self.navigationController.navigationBar.shadowImage = [UIImage new];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.clipsToBounds = YES;
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
```

cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
cell.backgroundColor = myColor;
```

Comment: Is your navigation bar set to be opaque or translucent?

Comment: @Orkster -  My navigation bar is set to be opaque (Translucency set to ``NO``)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setShadowImage:[[UIImage alloc] init]];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage alloc]init] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

But if you want to remove the hairline alone and keeping the blur effect, try:

`self.navigationController.navigationBar.clipsToBounds = YES;`

and by the way, this is my actual code of testing:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIView *red = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 44, 44)];
    red.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [self.view addSubview:red];

    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.clipsToBounds = YES;
}
```

Sample output be:

[image]

**Update:**

Looks like `-clipToBounds` do not suits your implementation.
Here what i think suits yours:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0.5 blue:0.97 alpha:1.0];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setShadowImage:[[UIImage alloc] init]];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage alloc]init] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
```

---

```
Before:                            After:
```

[image]    [image]

**Note:** The `[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0.5 blue:0.97 alpha:1.0]` is just for example, assign your desired color to `.barTintColor`.

Perhaps

```
//0084D3
UIColor * color = [UIColor colorWithRed:0/255.0f green:132/255.0f blue:211/255.0f alpha:1.0f]; 

//006FCC
UIColor * color = [UIColor colorWithRed:0/255.0f green:111/255.0f blue:204/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
```

is what you need based from [UIColor Code Generator](http://uicolor.org) :)

Hope this is helpful.. Cheers.. :)

Comment: This is almost perfect. The border gets taken away, but then the status bar gets wiped off. It turns completely white/grayish.

Comment: @alvarolopez, Maybe this  is all you need `self.navigationController.navigationBar.clipsToBounds = YES;` dont call the `setShadowImage` and `setBackgroundImage` .. and maybe `.translucent = NO`;  in your implementation is needed..

Comment: Nope, whatever I change, if ``clipToBounds = NO`` then the status bar is not blue. Actually your screenshot shows too the color is not carried to the status bar.

Comment: Code added to original question

Comment: Note: In the previous comment I meant  ``clipToBounds = YES``

Comment: Yes, that did it! It seems the combination of both ``shadowImage`` and ``backgroundImage`` was needed. Thank you very much. Marked as accepted answer :)

Answer (score 1):

The line you're seeing is the navigation bar's shadowImage. You can remove it by adding

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.shadowImage = [UIImage new];
```

**EDIT**

Not sure if you've solved this already, but I set up a brand new project with a UITableViewController embedded in a UINavigationController and there's no line under the nav bar. Here's the configuration I did:
In viewDidLoad:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBarTintColor:myColor];
self.tableView.backgroundColor = myColor;
self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
```

In tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
cell.contentView.backgroundColor = myColor;
cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = myColor;
cell.textLabel.text = @"this";
```

Nothing special in Storyboard.

[image]

Comment: That did not fix it. I did a clean run and still seeing that shadow :/

Comment: Yep, I tried your code and there is no shadow. However, the blue color of the navigation bar gets taken away, so it is of no use. Why wouldn't it work if it is not transparent?

Comment: Edits updated with example from a fresh project. Hopefully, it helps.

Comment: I just can't replicate what you are doing. I copy your code and replace the colors and that border is still in its place.